# View does not display results when added as a block to a region

Tags: views, blocks

UPDATE 2: I'm not sure if this is relevant but when click 'demonstrate block regions' the only region it displays is content

---

UPDATE: I have just discovered that the block displays just fine when added to the content region. However when added to any other region such as the left sidebar or any custom region it does not display at all

---

I currently have a view that displays the results just fine in the view preview. It also works when I create a basic page and embed it like so:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('mobile_slide_menu','block');?>
```

However when I add this view to a region it displays no results. However I know that it's trying to display something because I see this in my source.

```
<div class="region region-slide-menu">

</div>
```

My info file that is defining the regions looks like this

```
;regions
regions[main_menu] = Main Menu
regions[header] = Header
regions[content] = Content
regions[help] = Help
regions[slide_menu] = Slide Menu
regions[footer] = Footer
regions[sidebar_first] = Left Sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Right Sidebar
```

and I'm calling the region like this

```
<?php print render($page['slide_menu']);?>
```

I'm using Drupal 7 and this is a custom theme I've built. I've cleared the cache multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the location of

```
<?php print render($page['slide_menu']);?>
```

Placing it inside of a unordered list prevented it from rendering anything. Not even in the source.
Placing it outside of the list allowed it to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

Verify which of the blocks you have enabled for the theme you're using. To do so, navigate to admin/structure/block. Somewhere your "block created with views" should be listed there. If it is within "Disabled" (near the bottom), then you need to indicate there in which region (like sidebar 1st, sidebar 2nd  or something similar?) you want that block to be displayed.

From what you seem to experience, it seems that hardly any block is enabled (most seem to be disabled).

PS: just to be sure, try to clear the cache ... it doesn't hurt, but sometimes that is what is required ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the region slide_menu and the block is assigned to that region. It is set to display on all pages except <front> would there be any other way for it to be disabled?

Comment: It is a custom theme I have built using Drupal 7

Comment: Hm, a "custom" theme ... That's another story. From what I read/know now, I believe your problem is not in the view. But just some problem to have your theme correctly process (display) all data of all enabled blocks in each of your regions. Try this: create a custom bock with just some "test"-text in the block to be displayed. via admin, make that block show up in (eg) region sidebar 1st. And then verify if the block is actually shown. I'm about sure it won't show up either. That eliminates the possibility that the error is in your view. And something in your theme's php files is the issue.